# Whats difference between heroku and github

Tags: heroku, github, production

What does it mean production in rails , whats the difference between using github and heroku at the same time . I used github for like a backup / how all of us gonna use heroku . Is it necessary ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming even in the slightest.  Try googling.

Comment: Please let me know if that helps! They are off topic but it was their first question!

Comment: @siddhu could you mark my question with the check ... if you need more help let me know!

Answer (score 12):

First I need to explain GIT

**Git** is a distributed version control and source code management (SCM) system with an emphasis on speed. Initially designed and developed by Linus Torvalds for Linux kernel development in 2005. Every Git working directory is a full-fledged repository with complete history and full version tracking capabilities, not dependent on network access or a central server.

**GitHub** is a web-based hosting service for software development projects that use the Git revision control system. The site provides social networking functionality such as feeds, followers and the social network graph to display how developers work on their versions of a repository.

**Heroku** (pronounced her-OH-koo) is a web host that uses the Git revision control system. When you push your code to Heroku using git it then builds your server just like you do when you use locate host but for everyone to see.

Heroku is a cloud application platform – a new way of building and deploying web apps. The service lets app developers spend their time on their application code, not managing servers, deployment, ongoing operations, or scaling.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub is a web-based hosting service for projects which uses Git version control system(VCS) It's a code repository where you can store code for better collaboration & contribution. Anybody can contribute to your open source code via cloning it & github will make a branch of code. You can also purchase $9/mth to create private repositories for private collaboration. You can deploy code with Git but you need your own server to host that code.

Visit https://github.com/about

heroku is a PaaS(Platform as a service) web apps hosting service where you can build & deploy web apps. Build great web apps, collaborate & deploy as well with heroku.

Visit https://www.heroku.com/about

Heroku comes with it's own server so you can purchase hosting plan & deploy you web apps easily. In case of Github you need to purchase a separate server to host your web apps.
Github is well known for contribution & collaboration & Heroku is for backend stack available for collaboration & deploying easily.